# How can I get Google gtag content grouping not set after code to work?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

### How To Reproduce

1. Define Content Group Name And Index# in View Content Groupings
2. Turn Status On
3. Add code:

```
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxx-xx"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx-xx', {'content_group1': 'Drug-Related Criminal Defense'});
</script>
</head>
```

( The `content_group1` value is the page title. Unsure if that needs to be a directory path? `xxxxx-xx` is masking true GA ID. )

---

## The Results

[image: Google Analytics Content Grouping]

---

## Desired Affect

`(not set)` should populate the value of the `content_group1` value `Drug-Related Criminal Defense` unless I'm supposed to provide a directory path? The documentation wasn't clear to me.

Comment: People are allowed to vote however they choose (up, down or not at all), and they do not need to leave a comment or try to edit the question instead of or in addition to downvoting, they can if they choose but there's no obligation and they certainly don't need to be reminded to.

Comment: @NickA I saw nothing in the code of conduct or behavior that would prohibit that reminder. I'm just merely reminding anyone to vote what they feel; leave a comment or edit in addition to vote. I saw nothing wrong, otherwise. IMHO

Comment: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) literally says at the top "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." So it was entirely appropriate to remove a portion of your question that was not actually related to your question. That said, it is true that far too many people downvote or vote to close without trying to engage or clarify the problem. You have a couple of close votes already - I would suggest you focus on clarifying the question, rather than trying to understand people.

Comment: @Prisoner comments directly related to improving the question. You helped! I've added to it with what I wish to accomplish from my code example.

Comment: Well i am still not sure i understand your question, but i will try to give you an idea of what it means.  As its a Google analytics thing i am not really sure you can fix it or what it has to do with content_group1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code in Liquid. I used `gtag('set', {}` instead.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{site.google_analytics_tracking_id}}"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag('js', new Date());gtag('config','{{site.google_analytics_tracking_id}}');{% if page.groupid %}gtag('set', {'content_group{{page.groupid}}': '{{page.title}}'});{% endif %}
</script>
```

Data is now populating for what I want.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[What the value (not set) means](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en)

(not set) is a placeholder name that Analytics uses when it hasn't received any information for the dimension you have selected. The reasons for (not set) appearing as a dimension value vary according to the report.

Additional info [How to Quickly Discover and Solve (Not Set) Issues in Google Analytics](https://online-metrics.com/not-set-google-analytics/)  or just google Google analytics Not set there are loads of blob posts about it.

## data processing latency

[Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.

Comment: I read the docs. My code should be populating the value of `content_group1` with `Drug-Related Criminal Defense` for the specific page I'm testing the site wide code snippet. The value changes with page title. I was unsure if I wrote the gtag code incorrectly with the expected value.

Comment: only if there is data that matches the dates you are searching, and the metrics and dimensions.  IF no data exists then your going to get not set.  Also remember there is a data processing latency its going to take up to 48 hours before you see anything

Comment: @DalmTo Which is why I provided a screenshot. The value is the dimension I believed?

Comment: and the reset of them are metrics.  You didn't say what date you are searching preforming analysis for.  Nor the date that you added this in both google analytics and google tag manager

Comment: Sept 12-18, 2019 and the test was an hour ago.

Comment: Well again google analytics has a data processing latency.  Dont check for an hour ago check for three days ago.  Is there data then? probably not becouse you only just added it to GTM.  You need to wait and see if the data shows up in a few days.

Comment: @DalmTo ok I will wait three days to see if the code is valid. Thanks!